# Class based view not returning httpresponse when reversing in an httpresponseredirect?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I've been trying to figure this out for some time now but don't see how the error message im getting really is the case. I'm getting this error message:

```
The view plan.views.PortfolioReportEdit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

From looking at the code it does seem to return an httpresponse at any place it should from my point of view.

Here is the code, first for the parent/superclass:

```
class PortfolioEditBase(UpdateView):
    post_req = False
    url_name = 'plan:view_investment_profile'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.post_req = True
        print "BASE: form_valid passed"
        return super(PortfolioEditBase, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PortfolioEditBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        try:
            context['post_req'] = self.post_req
            context['profile_id'] = self.kwargs['profile_id']
            print "BASE: gathered context data"
            return context
        except KeyError:
            context['post_req'] = self.post_req
            print "BASE: gathered context data"
            return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        print "PortfolioEditBASE: in success_url"
        return reverse(self.url_name, args=self.kwargs['profile_id'])
```

Here is the code for the subclass:

```
class PortfolioDividendEdit(PortfolioEditBase):
    model = Dividend
    form_class = DividendForm
    template_name = 'plan/portfolio/edit/dividend_edit.html'
    print "PortfolioDividendEdit: Inside start of function"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if "delete" in self.request.POST:
            div_obj = Dividend.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['dividend_id'])
            profile_id = div_obj.profile_id
            div_obj.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('plan:view_investment_profile', kwargs={'profile_id': profile_id}))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print "Inside get_context_data dividend"
        context = super(PortfolioEditBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dividend_obj = Dividend.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['dividend_id'])
        profile = Profile.objects.get(id=dividend_obj.profile_id)
        context['post_req'] = self.post_req
        context['profile'] = profile
        context['dividend_id'] = self.kwargs['dividend_id']
        print "PortfolioDividendEdit: Returning context"
        print "PortfolioDividendEdit: context: " + str(context)
        return context

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = Dividend.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['dividend_id'])
        print "PortfolioDividendEdit: Returning object"
        print "Object: " + str(obj)
        return obj

    def get_success_url(self):
        print "PortfolioDividendEdit: Inside get_success_url"
        dividend_obj = Dividend.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['dividend_id'])
        profile_id = dividend_obj.profile_id
        print "GET SUCCESS URL"
        print self.url_name
        print profile_id
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(self.url_name, args=[profile_id]))
```

According to django the subclass does not return an HttpResponse which i cannot figure out why it doesnt do as I am returning an HttpResponseRedirect with a reverse inside of it which I though would work but for some reason is not.

This is output of the print lines from the log:PortfolioEditReport: Returning object

```
PortfolioEditReport: object is: Earnings report
Not Found: /plan/portfolio/investment-info-reports/edit/css/style.css
[06/Aug/2018 15:16:00] "GET /plan/portfolio/investment-info-reports/edit/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 8627
PortfolioEditReport: Gathered context data
[06/Aug/2018 15:16:00] "GET /plan/portfolio/investment-info-reports/edit/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 7112
PortfolioEditReport: Returning object
PortfolioEditReport: object is: Earnings report
Internal Server Error: /plan/portfolio/investment-info-reports/edit/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 198, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view plan.views.PortfolioReportEdit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[06/Aug/2018 15:16:02] "POST /plan/portfolio/investment-info-reports/edit/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 56676
```

It never seems to execute get_success_url and the last thing seems to be returning an object but nothing more.

Any ideas why this is not working ?

Comment: Note that the traceback is for `PortfolioReportEdit`. You have shown a different view `PortfolioDividendEdit`. However, looking at `PortfolioDividendEdit.form_valid`, you don't return anything when `if "delete" in self.request.POST:` is not `True`. Also, in your `get_success_url` method you should be returning a *URL* (e.g. `return reverse(...)`), not a response (e.g. `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(...))`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check it out. Sorry about posting the wrong view, but they are very similar and the same problem exists with this view that I posted so the same problem is probably in this view as well. I'll look into both your observations..

Comment: Both form_valid and get_success_url needed the changes you described and the view is now working as it should